# sharing memory across different python processes(spawned on unix)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

We have a application where we start multiple python processes and each process cache huge data (5-10 GB). is there a way i could cache this data and share the memory across all my python processes. I read about Managers(), pipe etc but they all seems to be good if all the processes are sub-process of one common parent process. my scenrio is like below .
I spawn my processes as

```
./start_my_process.sh 1
./start_my_process.sh 2
./start_my_process.sh 3
```

This would invoke 3 different thread where actual logic happening is same but on different set of i/p based on argument i pass with each command. Now all these 3 Processes are caching the data... i want to put it at central place and make it accessible to all these 3 processes. is it available straight out of python or i have to go for some sort of in memory cache eg hazelcast, Apache ignite etc

Comment: What are you using now, threads or processes? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Upon another look, I think what you are looking for is something like memcached or redis.

Comment: When I said thread, I meant Unix threads which actually is a python process

Comment: @Azsgy thats what i am reaching also....but wanted to check if there is anything available from python which i can use.... going for external memory caching would be lot of effort (installation\licensing\implemention etc)

Comment: IMO, any custom solution you come up with will likely be worse in every way than just using memcached/redis. Installing/running those takes 1-2 commands, they are both free software and implementation is as easy as importing a library. Also consider that you don't only have to save the information, you have to make sure the cache doesn't grow to large, expire it and make sure it doesn't break if two programs access it at the same time